# Can't connect from outside to Postgres running on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, aws-security-group

I have installed Postgres 10 on my EC2 ubuntu(18). But I can't access it from my Local Mac. Get this error.

[image]

My SETUP is:

I updated Postgres configs:

1. to /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf added these lines:

```
    host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
    host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
```

2. in /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf changed this line:

```
    listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

3. I did set password to default 'postgres' user, which I am using to connect to DB from outside;

On EC2 instance I changed:

1. added "Inbound rule" for port 5432 from any IPv4:
   [image]

On EC2 instance this command returns that port is exposed:

```
ubuntu@ip-XXXXXXXXXX:~$ netstat -nat |grep :5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Looks like EC2 instance did not expose this port in fact. Other ports like :80 or :22 are accessible fine, but port :5432 returns error:

```
➜  ~ nc -zv XX.XXX.XXX.XXX 80  
Connection to XX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 80 [tcp/http] succeeded!

➜  ~ nc -zv XX.XXX.XXX.XXX 5432
nc: connectx to XX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 5432 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```

I also have Nginx installed on my EC2 instance, its config is:

```
server {
  charset utf-8;
  listen 80;
  server_name XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ca; # <--- hidden domain name
  location / {
    root /opt/frontend/develop/dist/tweeter-ui/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api/;
  }
}
```

PostgreSQL service is running:

```
ubuntu@ip-XXXXXXXXXX:~$ service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2022-11-23 22:41:33 UTC; 1h 6min ago
  Process: 6283 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6283 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 23 22:41:33 ip-XXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Nov 23 22:41:33 ip-XXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

What is wrong in my setup? I tried many different posts in this forum and on Internet, nothing helps. ((
Do I have to also configure Nginx with Postgres routing?

Comment: Did you check your postgres service is running? You can run `service PostgreSQL status`

Comment: **From the instance itself**, can you run `psql` and connect to the database on `localhost`? Next, try connecting to it on the **private IP address** of the instance. Then, try connecting on the **public IP address**.

Comment: @DreamBold, yes service is running, I updated my post with the printout of command "$ service postgresql status"

Comment: As @JohnRotenstein mentioned, did you manage to connect `psql` from the terminal on the server with the current creds? `sudo -u postgres psql`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I just tried on EC2 instance`psql -d postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres` with my password - and it works.

Comment: @DreamBold the command `sudo -u postgres psql` also works, but it doesn't ask for password, is this normal?

Comment: Your password doesn't seem to work, you can try to run `\password postgres` to change the password for `postgres` user in the psql teminal

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Private IP also worked `psql -d postgres -h XXX.XX.XX.XX -p 5432 -U postgres`

Comment: When connecting to the private ip, doesn't it ask the password?

Comment: @DreamBold, ok I just changed password with your command `\password postgres`. Do I need to restart the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249843/discussion-between-dream-bold-and-renat-gatin).

Comment: @DreamBold it does ask for password - when connecting to the private ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You followed the correct steps. The issue is that the firewall is blocking the port of Postgres, 5432, so need to add it to the firewall allowed list.

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```

When you run `$ sudo ufw status`, you'll see:

```
Status: active

To Action From
-- ------ ----
OpenSSH ALLOW Anywhere
Nginx Full ALLOW Anywhere
5432/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
5432/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
```

And then run `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`, when you see `success`, you're done!

You will be able to connect from outside of the instance